# Extract plain model from tidymodel object

Tags: r, tidymodels

Is it possible to extract, say, a model of class `glm` from a `tidymodel` built with `recipe` and `logistic_reg() %>% set_engine("glm")`?

I'd like to use packages from the `easystats` project, which require "normal", non-tidy models. The workflow extractor function (`pull_workflow_fit()`) returns an object of class `"_glm" "model_fit", which doesn't seem to be compatible.

I understand I can generate a model using `glm()` and the same formula as in the `recipe`, but it seems to me the fitted parameters differ.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [*easystats* package suite](http://easystats.github.io/easystats) supports tidymodels since the last updates:

```r
library(tidymodels)

data(two_class_dat)

glm_spec <- logistic_reg() %>%
  set_engine("glm") 

norm_rec <- recipe(Class ~ A + B, data = two_class_dat) %>%
  step_normalize(all_predictors())

workflow() %>%
  add_recipe(norm_rec) %>%
  add_model(glm_spec) %>%
  fit(two_class_dat) %>%
  pull_workflow_fit() %>% 
  parameters::model_parameters()
#> Parameter   | Log-Odds |   SE |         95% CI |     z |      p
#> ---------------------------------------------------------------
#> (Intercept) |    -0.35 | 0.10 | [-0.54, -0.16] | -3.55 | < .001
#> A           |    -1.11 | 0.17 | [-1.44, -0.79] | -6.64 | < .001
#> B           |     2.80 | 0.21 | [ 2.40,  3.22] | 13.33 | < .001


workflow() %>%
  add_recipe(norm_rec) %>%
  add_model(glm_spec) %>%
  fit(two_class_dat) %>%
  pull_workflow_fit() %>% 
  parameters::model_parameters() %>% 
  plot()
```

[image]

```r
workflow() %>%
  add_recipe(norm_rec) %>%
  add_model(glm_spec) %>%
  fit(two_class_dat) %>%
  pull_workflow_fit() %>% 
  parameters::model_parameters() %>% 
  parameters::print_md()
```

| Parameter | Log-Odds | SE | 95% CI | z | p |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| (Intercept) | -0.35 | 0.10 | (-0.54, -0.16) | -3.55 | < .001 |
| A | -1.11 | 0.17 | (-1.44, -0.79) | -6.64 | < .001 |
| B | 2.80 | 0.21 | (2.40, 3.22) | 13.33 | < .001 |

```r
workflow() %>%
  add_recipe(norm_rec) %>%
  add_model(glm_spec) %>%
  fit(two_class_dat) %>%
  pull_workflow_fit() %>% 
  performance::model_performance()
#> # Indices of model performance
#> 
#> AIC     |     BIC | Tjur's R2 |  RMSE | Sigma | Log_loss | Score_log | Score_spherical |   PCP
#> ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#> 679.950 | 693.970 |     0.460 | 0.362 | 0.925 |    0.426 |      -Inf |           0.003 | 0.733
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You can extract out the underlying model object (whether that was created by glm or ranger or keras or anything) from a parsnip object using `$fit`.

```r
library(tidymodels)

data(two_class_dat)

glm_spec <- logistic_reg() %>%
  set_engine("glm") 

norm_rec <- recipe(Class ~ A + B, data = two_class_dat) %>%
  step_normalize(all_predictors())

glm_fit <- workflow() %>%
  add_recipe(norm_rec) %>%
  add_model(glm_spec) %>%
  fit(two_class_dat) %>%
  pull_workflow_fit()
```

What is in that fitted object?

```r
## this is a parsnip object
glm_fit
#> parsnip model object
#> 
#> Fit time:  5ms 
#> 
#> Call:  stats::glm(formula = ..y ~ ., family = stats::binomial, data = data)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)            A            B  
#>     -0.3491      -1.1063       2.7966  
#> 
#> Degrees of Freedom: 790 Total (i.e. Null);  788 Residual
#> Null Deviance:       1088 
#> Residual Deviance: 673.9     AIC: 679.9

## this is a glm object
glm_fit$fit
#> 
#> Call:  stats::glm(formula = ..y ~ ., family = stats::binomial, data = data)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)            A            B  
#>     -0.3491      -1.1063       2.7966  
#> 
#> Degrees of Freedom: 790 Total (i.e. Null);  788 Residual
#> Null Deviance:       1088 
#> Residual Deviance: 673.9     AIC: 679.9
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

The fitted parameters will definitely not differ from calling the model directly. If you think you are finding different fitted parameters, then something may be going awry is how you are calling the model.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your solution! May I say that this aspect could use a little more elaboration in `tidymodel`'s documentation? It allows you to easily switch between `tidymodels` and other ecosystems such as `easystats` which do not support tidy-style. I followed `tidymodels` tutorial to the letter but I don't think this "interoperability" feature ever came up, even though it may seem obvious to expert users.

Comment: Thanks for that feedback! We'll look into making that more clear.