# error checking glmnet model from parsnip object using easystats: $ operator is invalid

Tags: r, tidymodels, r-parsnip

Tried to check_model using a very simple glmnet classification task.

Taken some Code from here:
[Extract plain model from tidymodel object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65969913/extract-plain-model-from-tidymodel-object)

```
library(magrittr)
library(tidymodels)
library(performance)

data(two_class_dat)

glm_spec <- logistic_reg() %>%
  set_engine("glmnet")

norm_rec <- recipe(Class ~ A + B, data = two_class_dat) %>%
  step_normalize(all_predictors())

glm_fit <- workflow() %>%
  add_recipe(norm_rec) %>%
  add_model(glm_spec) %>%
  fit(two_class_dat) %>%
  pull_workflow_fit()



performance::check_model(glm_fit)

Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Answer (score 0):

`performance::check_model()` is a generic function. This means that specific functions (called the methods) need to be written for `check_model()` to work on different types of objects. I think that they would need to write a method for workflow objects.

In your example, you probably wouldn't want to run `check_model()` on the fitted model since it doesn't know about the pre-processing in your recipe.

It looks like this SO question was converted to an issue [here](https://github.com/easystats/performance/issues/301).

Comment: Yes. It is a bug